# how to navigate to the next page if a password input is correct in google app script

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

I am handling a project in app script and I am done with the web app but need  a login before users can access the app/form. But I am having issues creating a login page as I want to create username and password input if correct before users can be allowed to proceed from login page to app page. Please help me here is my server code.

```
function doGet(e) {
  if (e.parameters.page == "apppage"){
  return loadAppPage();
}
else{
  return loadLoginPage();
}


function loadLoginPage(){
  return HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile('loginPage').evaluate();
}

function loadLoginPage(){
  return HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile('loginPage').evaluate();
}
```

JavaScript Code:

```
document.getElementById('loginbutton').addEventListener ('click', getlogin); 

function getlogin(){
  var username= document.getElementById ('username').value; 
  var password= document.getElementById ('password').value; 
  if(username=='admin' && password == 'admin123'){
   loginbutton.setAttribute("href",ScriptApp.getService().getUrl()+loginPage);
  }
}
```

Comment: Why do you have two loadLoginPage() functions?

Comment: Perhaps this will help: https://stackoverflow.com/a/46943386/7215091

Comment: Or perhaps this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/55770563/7215091

Answer (score 1):

Instead of setting the attribute href, just navigate to page

```
function getlogin(){
  var username= document.getElementById ('username').value; 
  var password= document.getElementById ('password').value; 
  if(username=='admin' && password == 'admin123'){
   google.script.run.navigateTo('your_page')
  }
}
```

[Read more here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36485791/11719787)